# Android: Handling events in menu

Tags: android

I am trying to implement smth like context menu but with icons

```
public class MenuItem {
    private  int type; 
    private String nameItem;
    private int imageResource;
}
menu.xml 
// ImageView ant TextView

public final class  MenuItemProvider {
//create our menu items
}

   public class MenuListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItem> {
 private Activity context;
 private List<MenuItem> menuItems;

 public MenuListAdapter(Activity context, List<MenuItem> menuItems) {
        super(context, R.menu.menudlg, menuItems);

        this.context = context;
        this.menuItems = menuItems;
      }
 @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.menu.menudlg, parent, false);

    TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_item);
    label.setText(menuItems.get(position).getName());

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon_item);
    icon.setImageResource(menuItems.get(position).getImageResource());

    return row;
  }
```

}

**Question** I don't understand how to handle event in this menu(event of filled menu item), one of the ways send in builder.setAdapter dialogListener ,but i don't know how create them

```
    listView = getListView();        
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
       builder.setTitle(title);
       builder.setAdapter(new AccountsTypesListAdapter(context, AccountTypesProvider.accountTypes), dialogListener);
    builder.create().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow your approach here.  Have you read [Creating Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)?

All you should have to do is define your menu xml file, inflate it in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and handle the menu selection in `onOptionsItemSelected`.

I'm not sure why you have an ArrayAdapter involved.

Comment: yes i red this article, i want to create smth like context menu but with images

Comment: Ah, ok the "context menu" part was missing from your question I think.  A dialog is like a separate activity, so you return information from it just like an activity, via the response code or intent extras.